# Proper way to store user defined data in SQL

Tags: sql, forms, database-design, normalization, entity-attribute-value

I want to build an online form builder much like wufoo that allows the users to create and publish their own web forms. Each submission should be saved to a data base where the user can later retrieve the submissions.

As these forms will be dynamic, ie. the user has complete control over the amount and type of form fields I am trying to think of a solid database design to store this information.

I would have one table fieldtype which contains every type of field available to the users, ie. textfield, emailfield etc.

One baseform table which will hold each forms id, url etc.

I would then have a table formfields which would contain ref to the baseform and to fieldtype, this table could also include custom validation to be done on each field.

Is this design good as a base structure? I imagine it will be easy to add new types of fields to the application however I don't know what the potential downsides are as I am far from a sql expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> store user defined data in SQL

I think you are looking for the [Entity–attribute–value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) database model in which:

> The basic idea is to store attributes, and their corresponding values,
>   as rows in a single table.
>
> Typically the table has at least three columns: entity, attribute, and
>   value. Though if there is only a single relevant entity, e.g. a table
>   for application configuration or option settings, the entity column
>   can be excluded.

See this pages as a start:

- [Using Database Metadata and its Semantics to Generate Automatic and Dynamic Web Entry Forms](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCECS2007/WCECS2007_pp654-658.pdf) (pdf)
- [Planning and Implementing a Metadata-Driven Digital Repository](http://scholarspace.manoa.hawaii.edu/bitstream/handle/10125/337/0409CCQPlanningImplementing.pdf?sequence=1) (pdf)

I retagged your question with [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) tag, in which you can browse a lot of threads that relate to your case.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer entity-attribute-value was exactly the model I was looking for.

Comment: EAV is good known as a classis anti-pattern... http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/05/eav-fail.html you've chosen wrong path.

Comment: @Borys - You're right, but the OP is looking for a way to do `complete control over the amount and type of form fields`. How can you get the user the ability to create the fields of the forms and the types of the form with a normalized database model, where you can't know which attributes will be for each field?  It is dynamic, you can't tell which columns will be for each form.

Answer (score 0):

As Mahmoud Gamal writes, The model you describe is "Entity/Attribute/Value"; as Borys writes, there are many known problems with this model.

As an alternative, you might consider storing the form entries in a "document" - e.g. XML or JSON - within a relational model.

For instance, you might have a table along the lines of:

```
FORM_SUBMISSION
--------------------
Submission_ID (pk)
Client_ID (fk to clients table)
Submission_date
SubmissionDocument
```

I'm using "client" to represent the users who create the form; to retrieve all submissions for a given client, you use a where clause on client_id.

This model makes it harder to run SQL queries against the form submission (though that becomes hard with EAV too when going beyond very simple queries), but it dramatically simplifies the persistence solution.