# PHP SQL join table rows as keys

Tags: php, sql, join

I was wondering if someone could help me.  I have the following two tables:

```
---Posts----

id  | title | content |  
544 | Alan  | Blah

---Postmeta----

metaid | post_id | meta_key | meta_value  
1      |  544    | age      | 45  
2      |  544    | email    | test@hotmail.co.uk
```

I want to join the two tables by post_id and then display the meta_keys.  Something like this

```
SELECT posts.post_id, 
       postmeta.age, 
       postmeta.email, 
FROM 
       posts  
JOIN posts 
ON posts.post_id = postmeta.post_id
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: You're joining `posts ON posts` instead of `posts ON postmeta`? Is that a typo in your question?

Comment: You're not far, you just made a little mistake: `posts.id` (not `posts.post_id`), `JOIN` is the correct way to go, just make yourself a little more comfortable with it. I suggest reading all about it in the PHP manual and also search for tutorials and books. Also first run your SQL in the commandline version of mysql so you can test before putting it into PHP code. Or if you like a GUI, take the Mysql GUI instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `PIVOT` the rows inside the table `postmeta` into columns, using `CASE` with `MAX` as an aggregate function to eliminate `NULL`s like so:

```
SELECT p.id, pm.age, pm.email
FROM posts p
JOIN
(
   SELECT
     post_id,
     MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'age'   THEN  meta_value END) AS age,
     MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'email' THEN meta_value END) AS email
   FROM postsmeta
   GROUP BY post_id
) pm ON p.id = pm.post_id
```

### Here is a [Demo in sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55e31/6)

**Note that:** You are currently storing all values for `age` and `email` in one column of the same data type that would be `varchar` for example then you have to cast the `age` values to `INT` in the query in order to get it like `INT` if you want to perform some calculations later on, and I left this part for you.

Comment: There is no `posts.post_id`, there is `posts.id`

Comment: thanks a million Mahmoud!  i was wondering to cast values to INT is it simply CAST(pm.age, INT) as age?

thanks again!

Comment: @user774715, If you interested, this database model called [Entity attribute value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), here is [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12300388/722783) if you want to read more about it

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  posts.id,
  postmeta.key,
  postmeta.meta_value
FROM
  posts
JOIN
  postmeta ON posts.id = postmeta.post_id
WHERE
  postmeta.key IN ('age', 'email')
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this

```
SELECT posts.post_id,
postmeta.age,
postmeta.email,
FROM
posts
JOIN postsmeta
ON posts.post_id = postmeta.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT posts.id, 
       postmeta.age, 
       postmeta.email, 
       m.meta_key, 
       m.meta_value
FROM 
       posts  p
JOIN Postmeta m
ON p.id = m.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining **twice** to the `postmeta` table:

```
SELECT p.id, 
       pm1.meta_value AS age, 
       pm2.meta_value AS email
FROM 
       posts AS p
  LEFT JOIN 
       postmeta AS pm1
    ON pm1.post_id = p.id
   AND pm1.meta_key = 'age'

  LEFT JOIN 
       postmeta AS pm2
    ON pm2.post_id = p.id 
   AND pm2.meta_key = 'email' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving meta_key in a new row, try to make your table structure like this

```
metaid | post_id | age | email  
1      |  544    | 45  | test1@hotmail.co.uk  
2      |  545    | 51  | test2@hotmail.co.uk  
3      |  546    | 20  | test3@hotmail.co.uk  
4      |  547    | 26  | test4@hotmail.co.uk
```

you can add more fields to table structure.

and after that you can make a simple join query, that will save your time and resources to execute the query.
like this

```
SELECT posts.post_id, postmeta.age, postmeta.email FROM posts JOIN postmeta ON posts.post_id = postmeta.post_id;
```